# Uploading Jupyter Notebook to Github with syntax highlighting

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, upload

I uploaded my first Jupyter Notebook to Github here:
https://github.com/Athelian/OkCupid/blob/master/OkC%20Analysis.ipynb

But I cannot figure out how to get syntax highlighting to display in the preview after clicking the link. I've noticed others don't have this issue when they upload .ipynb files.

Is there any way to get it display like a real notebook?